# Cannot access JSON array stored in native Shopify metafields

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm trying to access metafields containing an array that I want to loop over.

I've tried solutions online to no avail. Do you have any suggestions?

This is the JSON.

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Why do pets love CBD so much?",
    "pub": "ScienceDirect",
    "url": "https://www.efsa.europa.eu/en/news/cannabidiol-novel-food-evaluations-hold-pending-new-data"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "When will CBD take over the world",
    "pub": "Anna Research Institute",
    "url": "https://www.efsa.europa.eu/en/news/cannabidiol-novel-food-evaluations-hold-pending-new-data"
  }
]
```

The metafield is `article.metafields.custom.source_snippet`

In my article template I'm trying to access it via `{% assign sources = article.metafields.custom.source_snippet %}`

This usually worked with the old "Metafields Guru".

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In shopify there are actually two types of JSON metafields: `json` and `json_string`.

`json_string` is the old and deprecated type and `json` is the new version.

If your metafield was a `json_string` your code would have worked, but with `json` to access the actual value you need to add `.value` so your code should look like this

`{% assign sources = article.metafields.custom.source_snippet.value %}`